# Is there a C++ library for mesh modification?

Tags: library, c++

I am working on a surgery simulator using BulletPhysics for handling collision detection. I would like to simulate drilling a hole in a bone, which is represented by a mesh (.obj file).

Basically, I would need to refine the mesh where the drill bit hits the bone, and then move the vertices under the bit inside the bone to make a hole. Meshmixer can do that with its extrusion tool, but it doesn't have an API as far as I can tell.

If anybody knows of a library that can handle this, I would appreciate learning about it.

Thanks!